# Track/view hbase compaction job/status in Hbase shell

Tags: shell, hbase

I have run the Major compaction for a particular region in hbase shell. 
(within the terminal , with help of Hmaster node, via elinks i track if the Table content is Major or None)
but now i want to look into the percentage being done.
and is it possible in "hbase shell" prompt to track the ongoing status of Major compaction.